# What is wrong with this comment?

Tags: support

I tried to edit a comment I had written to be a little more complementary and self-explanatory, but SO wouldn't allow it. It said, [image: Comments can't contain that content.]

Why not? What is wrong with the below comment?

[image]

(I'm tagging this under `support` because I just want to know what rule I broke. There's probably already another `feature-request` question asking if this error can be more expressive. If not, I'll open that later.)

Comment: The `+1` is not allowed at this point in time.